# Dynatrace one agent in ecs fargate containers stops but application container is running

Tags: aws-fargate, dynatrace

Am trying to install one agent in my ECS fargate task. Along with application container i have added another container definition for one agent with image as alpine:latest and used run time injection.
While running the task, initially the one agent container is in running state and after a minute it goes to stopped state same time application container will be in running state.
In dynatrace the same host is available and keeps recreating after 5-10mins frequently.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem and connected via ssh to the cluster I saw that the agent needs to be privileged. The only thing that worked for me was sending traces and metrics through Opentelemetry.

https://aws-otel.github.io/docs/components/otlp-exporter

Alternative:

use `sleep infinity` in the command field of your oneAgent container.

Answer (score 0):

Actually the issue that I had was task was in draining status because of application issue due to which in dynatrace it keeps recreating... And the same time i used run time injection for my ECS fargate so once the binaries are downloaded and injected to volume, the one agent container definition will stop while the application container keeps running and injecting logs in dynatrace.